# Pandas: How to get the column name where a row contain the date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named `DateUnique` made of all unique dates (format datetime or string) that are present in my other dataframe named `A`.

```
>>> print(A)
          'dateLivraisonDemande'  'abscisse' 'BaseASDébut' 'BaseATDébut'  0                 2015-05-27  2004-01-10      05:00:00      05:00:00   
    1                 2015-05-27  2004-02-10      18:30:00      22:30:00   
    2                 2015-05-27  2004-01-20      23:40:00      19:30:00   
    3                 2015-05-27  2004-03-10      12:05:00      06:00:00   
    4                 2015-05-27  2004-01-10      23:15:00      13:10:00   
    5                 2015-05-27  2004-02-10      18:00:00      13:45:00   
    6                 2015-05-27  2004-01-20      02:05:00      19:15:00   
    7                 2015-05-27  2004-03-20      08:00:00      07:45:00   
    8                 2015-05-29  2004-01-01      18:45:00      21:00:00   
    9                 2015-05-27  2004-02-15      04:20:00      07:30:00   
    10                2015-04-10  2004-01-20      13:50:00      15:30:00
```

And:

```
>>> print(DateUnique)    
1       1899-12-30
2       1900-01-01
3       2004-03-10
4       2004-03-20
5       2004-01-20
6       2015-05-29
7       2015-04-10
8       2015-05-27
9       2004-02-15
10      2004-02-10
```

- How can I get the name of the columns that contain each date?
- Maybe with something similar to this:

  ```
  # input: 
  If row == '2015-04-10':
              print(df.name_Of_Column([0])) 

  # output: 
  'dateLivraisonDemande'
  ```

Comment: To elaborate: each date in `DateUnique` might be present in dataframe `A` in column `dateLivraisonDemande` or `abscisse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that returns the appropriate column.  Use the vectorized `isin` function, and then check if `any` value is `True`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dateLivraisonDemande': ['2015-05-27']*7 + ['2015-05-27', '2015-05-29', '2015-04-10'], 
                   'abscisse': ['2004-02-10', '2004-01-20', '2004-03-10', '2004-01-10', 
                                '2004-02-10', '2004-01-20', '2004-03-10', '2004-01-10', 
                                '2004-02-15', '2004-01-20']})

DateUnique = pd.Series(['1899-12-30', '1900-01-01', '2004-03-10', '2004-03-20',  
                        '2004-01-20', '2015-05-29', '2015-04-10', '2015-05-27', 
                        '2004-02-15', '2004-02-10'])

def return_date_columns(date_input):
    if df["dateLivraisonDemande"].isin([date_input]).any():
        return "dateLivraisonDemande"
    if df["abscisse"].isin([date_input]).any():
        return "abscisse"

>>> DateUnique.apply(return_date_columns)
0                    None
1                    None
2                abscisse
3                    None
4                abscisse
5    dateLivraisonDemande
6    dateLivraisonDemande
7    dateLivraisonDemande
8                abscisse
9                abscisse
dtype: object
```